# General co-browsing approach with common browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-domain, dom-events

I am looking for a solution to implement co-browsing (websites are synchronized between connected browsers) for unmodified, standard web browsers. I have an idea how to do it with [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).

However I would prefer to do it without the need to put code into the site which should be synchronized between browsers. This would enable co-browsing for "all" sites on the web. But the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prohibits reacting on events on a foreign website in an iframe in such a case.

There a solutions which only need Javascript and AJAX. No browser plugins or downloads needed.

How can this be achieved? What are the key techniques?

Comment: Hi nblumoe,

what do you want exactly, i dont understand your problem, 
i mean why do you want to synchronize connected browsers for which purpose ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. I am working on two web apps, which are based on the synchronization. First of all users (call them A+B) point their browsers to the url of the webapp. The webapp contains a remote site within an iframe. If user A "does something" in the site contained in the iframe, the same thing should happen in the browser of user B. This could be clicking a simple link or an ajax request. So I would like to catch events fired in the iframe of user A, pass the event to the browser of user B and fire the same event in the iFrame of user B.

Comment: I think your idea could not be feasible, iFrames do not capture events. This could be a security point!